# Problem in setting bottom border for UITextField in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I am new to swift. I have two UITextFields **email** and **password**. I want to add only bottom border to text fields and for that I am using the following method,

```
extension UITextField {

    func setBottomBorderWithLayer() {
        self.borderStyle = .none

        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 1.0)
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
      }

}
```

And this is how I am calling the method

```
emailTextField.setBottomBorderWithLayer()
passwordTextField.setBottomBorderWithLayer()
```

Now the problem is setBottomBorderWithLayer() method only setting bottom border for only emailTextField and not for passwordTextField.
Can anyone explain that where is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the code looks reasonable, obviously something about how you're configuring/laying out the two fields is causing only one to fail... I would try to compare what you're doing with both to see what the difference might be

the UI debugger might help give you some clues as well too.

Comment: A shadow is not a border; if the goal is to add a bottom border line to the text field, why don't you actually _do_ that?

Answer (score 0):

We need more details to be able to define where the error is, but **I suggest another type of implementation** that will meet your need.

Create a class that **extends** from **UITextField**, in this class you can define **all the necessary layout settings**, **facilitating reuse**, as you will only need to define the class in TextField from Storyboard -> TextField -> Identity Inspector -> Custom Class -> Class.

[image: Identity Inspector Class added]

Class example:

```
import UIKit

class BottomBorderTextField: UITextField {

    override init (frame: CGRect) {
        super.init (frame: frame)
        addBottomBorder()
    }

    required init? (coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init (coder: coder)
        addBottomBorder()
    }

    func addBottomBorder() {
        // Logic for adding style

        layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 0.0
        layer.cornerRadius = 5
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Silas, but just adding on here... 
If you want to create a colorful bottom bar to a textfield, this also works:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Utilities {

static func styleTextField(_ textfield:UITextField) {

    // Create the bottom line
    let bottomLine = CALayer()

    bottomLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textfield.frame.height - 2, width: textfield.frame.width, height: 2)

    bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 116/255, green: 203/255, blue: 128/255, alpha: 1).cgColor

    // Remove border on text field
    textfield.borderStyle = .none

    // Add the line to the text field
    textfield.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)

}
```